# Prevent OpenOffice Calc from converting pasted numbers with decimals into dates

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

Whenever I paste numbers that have dotted decimals in them (let's say, **5.05**) into an OpenOffice Calc Spreadsheet, it insists on converting them into dates (the above becomes **15-05-05**).

I usually set my spreadsheet cells to the **Number** or **Text** formats just to get rid of this annoyance. But doing so beforehand, does not prevent pasted data from being converted, at least if the source is from a web page.

How do I disable the date conversion feature?

Comment: Have you tried paste special?

Comment: @Lyrl Yes, I have tried that – both `Unfortmatted` and from `HTML` source – and in both cases it automatically converts to a date format.

Comment: Btw, sorry for my late reply, I accidentally missed your comment.

Comment: Could you give an example of a website you are copying from, and also share what OpenOffice version you are using?  I tested in OpenOffice 4.1.1 and was not able to reproduce the problem (although `5.05.` - with a second dot - did enter as a date).  I also tested in LibreOffice 4.4.4.3 and it always pasted as a number or as text (meaning 5.05 was a number and 5.05. was text).

Comment: @Lyrl This happens when I paste **5.05** from the question above. I'm using OpenOffice 4.1.2, but I'm pretty confident I had the same problem in the previous version.

Comment: I would say that's either a bug in 4.1.2, or specific to an operating system or locale setting; that behavior is not present on my Windows 10 system with 4.1.1 and a US locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had to do with my locale setting.

I had to change from a European locale to a U.S. one to use dotted decimals (`.`) without *OpenOffice Calc* interpreting it as dates. With the locale, it had a preference for colon decimals (`,`).

To change locale settings for *Numbers* data, without changing the locale of the entire software, I did this:

In Calc go to `Menu > Format > Styles and Formatting`, then right click *Default* and select *Modify*. Now go to `NUMBERS` and select *Numbers* data. Change *Language* to a US locale or something else that uses dotted decimals.